# igraph (c) access to each element of adjacency list

Tags: c++, c, igraph

I want to have access to each element of the adjacency list of generated graph in `igraph` in C. (to put it in a 2 dimensional vector later).

```
#include <igraph.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    igraph_t graph;
    igraph_rng_seed(igraph_rng_default(), 42);
    // generage a random graph
    igraph_erdos_renyi_game(&graph, IGRAPH_ERDOS_RENYI_GNP, 
                            1000, 
                            5.0/1000.0,
                            IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, 
                            IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS);
    // extract the adjacency list 
    igraph_adjlist_t adjlist;
    igraph_adjlist_init(&graph, &adjlist, IGRAPH_ALL);

    // print to file ??
    // ?? std::cout << adjlist[0][0] << std::endl;

    igraph_destroy(&graph);
    igraph_adjlist_destroy(&adjlist);
    return 0;
}
```

I the simple example above I have extracted the adjacency list [[igraph_adjlist.h]](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/include/igraph_adjlist.h).

**Edit**

It is possible to write the `adjlist` to a file by:

```
int igraph_write_graph_edgelist(const igraph_t *graph, FILE *outstream);

0 36
0 291
0 324
0 724
0 942
1 423
1 681
2 87
...
```

and read it again, but I am looking for a cleaner way.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: What do you mean by a "cleaner way"? The API `igraph_write_graph_edgelist` looks pretty straightforward and clean.

Comment: I have to write the adjlist to file and read it again to have access the edges. I am looking for a way to convert adjlist to a 2 dimensional vector or array. Now I cant have access for example to adjlist[0][0].

Comment: Can you try to write to file using `igraph_write_graph_edgelist()` and then take a look at its contents? It may be a simple comma-separated list and would be easy to read again in a vector.

Comment: I did, it is a two column file separated by a space. it is easy to read it to a vector but I lost some performance for large files.

Comment: Well, that's predictable behavior. If the file sizes increases, so the read operations and it'll take more time. You read file in multiple threads for large files (each thread reading a specific portion of file). What is the performance hit? Please update that code as well in your question.

Comment: There are multiple formats listed here (https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Foreign.html). You can check these also for performance comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjacency lists in igraph are documented here:

- https://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#igraph-Adjlists

An adjacency list is just a collection of vectors containing the vertex IDs of the direct neighbours of each vertex.

Thus, simply use

```
igraph_adjlist_get(adjlist, vertex)
```

to get the list of neighbours of `vertex` as an `igraph_vector_int_t`.

If you want the incident edges instead of adjacent vertices, create an [incidence list](https://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#idm470960803840) instead of adjacency list.

Example:

```
igraph_inclist_t inclist;

igraph_inclist_init(&graph, &inclist, IGRAPH_ALL);

igraph_vector_int_t *edges = igraph_inclist_get(&il, vertex);
igraph_integer_t first_neighbour = IGRAPH_OTHER(&graph, VECTOR(*edges)[0], vertex);

igraph_inclist_destroy(&inclist);
```